# How can I create a list of classes in C# to iterate over in a loop

Tags: c#, oop, class, inheritance, list

Suppose I have class `animal` and classes `cat` and `dog` extending it. I want to do something along the lines of:

```
foreach (class a in {cat, dog})  
    if (a.isValid(parameters))  
      doStuff();
```

isValid is a static method from animal that just checks if the given parameters define an object of the given type
doStuff means I'm doing stuff that I didn't feel was worth coppying over
@which objects are you talking about? hopefully my other edits clear this up
**I'm not starting with an object and trying to determine it's type. I'm starting with parameters and trying to decide which animal type to instantiate as.** So something like BlueRaja suggested, but without needing constructors.

My only alternative is a switch statement for each class, something I'd like to avoid.

Thanks,
J-B

Comment: Can you be more clear on where your objects are coming from?

Comment: Question is not very clear about what you want to accomplish. What is isValid? why doesn't doStuff take any parameters?

Comment: Your question is confusing. It is unclear whether you are iterating over the TYPES cat and dog or INSTANCES of those types. It is completely unclear what IsValid means since "static" and "virtual" are *opposites*; there are no "static virtual" methods. Can you give more details in the question?

Comment: you're right, static virtual turned out to not exist, they're static methods which all subclasses of animal have in common

Comment: @Jean: Individual static methods on different subclasses have no useful relationship to each other.  If that is really what you're trying to do, then it completely changes the question and isn't possible to do without reflection or other hacks.

Comment: It's a method that is inherited from animal. 
And I'm trying to itterate through classes extending animal without creating instances of them. I'm not looking for typeOf() since I don't have an instance to check against. I realise in my haste I made a major typo in the foreach loop, it should be foreach (class a in(..)) instead of foreach(animal..) this might make things clearer

Comment: @Jean: Static methods are not inherited, and are not meant to be related between classes.  If it is behavior which is truly common to all classes, simply change it to be non-static virtual.

Comment: @Jean: "class" is your example is a syntax error, so this version isn't much more illuminating.  The closest thing is the `Type` class, which is what I used.

Comment: Ok so I suppose I can't do what it is I orginially wanted to. I'll stick with the switch statement since while not elegant it gets the job done. I'm quite embarassed that I've managed to convince you all that I don't understand inheritance or polymorphism, (which I think is not the case :P )

Comment: @BlueRaja: Static methods are inherited. Static *constructors* are not inherited, but static *methods* are inherited.

Comment: @Eric: Once again, you are right and I am wrong.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  var types = a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why everyone made this so complicated

```
foreach (Animal a in new Animal[] {new Cat(), new Dog()})  
    if (a.isValid(parameters))  
        doStuff();
```

Comment: Well unless `Cat`/`Dog` has its parameters set internally I don't see the purpose in this....

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `typeof` operator:

```
Type[] types = new[] { typeof(Cat}, typeof(Dog) };
foreach (Type animalType in types)
{
    // ...
}
```

Although what you've got *inside* the loop doesn't really make sense for this; you can't cast `Type` to `Animal` and it's a bit hard to understand what the `isValid` method is supposed to be doing.

It almost sounds like you just want a `virtual` method, but some clarification might be in order.

Edit:

> I'm not starting with an object and trying to determine it's type. I'm starting with parameters and trying to decide which animal type to instantiate as.

That's a **Factory Method**, then, and a `switch` statement really is the best way to implement it:

```
public enum AnimalType
{
    Cat,
    Dog,
    ...
}

public static class AnimalFactory
{
    public static Animal CreateAnimal(AnimalType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case AnimalType.Cat:
                return new Cat();
            case AnimalType.Dog:
                return new Dog();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a DI library such as Autofac instead, that will allow you to simply register or even scan for the types and instantiate them via a factory method like this one, but internally it's doing much the same thing as the code above.

Comment: I'm not starting with an object and trying to determine it's type. I'm starting with parameters and trying to decide which animal type to instantiate as.

Answer (score 1):

Define IsValid and doStuff as a virtual methods in the animal base class and override them in the cat and dog classes to perform the appropriate behavior to the class.  Then you won't need a switch statement in your loop.

Comment: I'm not starting with an object, I'm starting with the parameters and checking to see which objects they define

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Cast extension method.  It allows you to cast any IEnumerable (including lists and arrays) for use in a foreach loop:

```
foreach (animal a in GetMyCatandDogList()
                    .Cast<animal>()
                    .Where(a => a.IsValid(parameters))
{
    DoStuff(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your animal classes implement an interface e.g. IAnimal, then just create a generic list to hold all different types of animals in the one list.

You would then make your IsValid method virtual in the base class (or even abstract) and override it per animal type. You can then expose this as a method on your interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type animal = typeof(Animal);

    foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (animal.IsAssignableFrom(t))
        {
            //dog or cat hit.
        }
    }
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to enumerate all classes in an assembly by calling method `Assembly.GetTypes()`.

You can get a list of loaded assemblies by calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies`, or you can load your assemblies from disk by calling static methods `Assembly.Load` or `Assembly.LoadFrom`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i'm out of line, but maybe you are searching for a type switch. This [blog post](http://blog.ashmind.com/2007/09/20/simple-typeswitch-in-c-30-part-2-the-solutions/) gives a good explanation and implementation, although you can find more alternative implementations on google.

Note the dthorpe's solution is perfectly valid and looks like a better fit to what you seem to achieve

Answer (score 0):

> > I'm not starting with an object and trying to determine it's type. I'm starting with parameters and trying to decide which animal type to instantiate as.

Really? Your question really doesn't convey this.

At any rate, let's give it a go.

Given a string parameter, we may want to create either a `Cat` or a `Dog`. Let's write a function which does that:

```
public Animal CreateAnimal(string parameter)
{
    if(parameter == "cat")
        return new Cat();
    else
        return new Dog();
}

var strings = new[]{ "cat", "cat", "dog" };
var animals = strings.Select(s => CreateAnimal(s)).ToList();
```

This seems all well and good, but what happens if we don't know what `Cat` and `Dog` are at compile time? Well, at some point we have to have a dictionary which maps parameters to actual types. We can look in this dictionary to find the type, then create an instance of it.

The code would look a bit like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Type> lookup = {
    { "cat", typeof(Cat) },
    { "dog", typeof(Dog) },
    { "fish", typeof(Fish) }, // people can add things to lookup dynamically
}

public Animal CreateAnimal(string parameter)
{
    var animalType = lookup[parameter];
    return (Animal)Activator.CreateInstance(animalType);
}
```

This will work, but there are 2 problems.

1. `Activator.CreateInstance` is not the fastest thing in the world. Generally it's fine but if you're creating 100,000 animals you'll notice
2. More importantly, because we are just storing types and doing casts to `Animal`, the compiler can't check anything for us. We could put `typeof(Ferrari)` in the dictionary and it would all compile fine, but it would crash when the app was run.

The next step is to use generics. Instead of storing the `Type` in the dictionary, we can store a lambda function which does the work of creating the animal. That way, we can use generics, and the compiler can fully check that all the animals are legit.

```
public static Dictionary<string, Func<Animal>> lookup = {
    { "cat", () => new Cat() },
    { "dog", () => new Dog() },
    { "fish", () => new Fish() }, // people can add things to lookup dynamically
}

public Animal CreateAnimal(string parameter)
{
    var creatorFunc = lookup[parameter];
    return creatorFunc(); // call the lambda which does the creating
}
```

Hope this helps!